# Device Detection Rules not triggering

Tags: rules-engine, device-detection

I am using `Sitecore 9.0.1` where I have created a new device (in the name of "AMP") item under `layout/device` in my content editor.

I would be configuring `Layouts/Renderings` (AMP files) in my page items for the AMP device.

Now I am trying to detect the requests to my site through a mobile device and redirect them to AMP items - for this, I have created a Rule `where device type is Mobile Phone`.

But somehow the rule is not triggering. Can anyone help? Please find attached screenshot for the same.

[image]

Comment: Has your device detection been enabled? Are you getting anything in the logfiles?

Comment: By default this setting <setting name="DeviceDetection.Enabled" value="true" /> is set to true

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same issue in 9.2 and think it's a bug so I opened to support ticket to get confirmation on this.

You can use this blog https://bala.one/sitecore-device-detection/ that has some information on how to check that the device detection is actually working. If you can confirm that and have no related issues in your logs, you should open a Sitecore support ticket as well to get the rule fixed (or write your own version - I'll share mine as soon as it's written and tested).

Just one question though: how are you testing this? Are you using a simulator (like in Chrome) or an actual mobile device? If you are using a simulator, make sure that you are starting a fresh session to make the first call immediately with the correct device as the rules seem to be using the information from the tracker.